# Teradata Interval function

Tags: sql, function, date, teradata, intervals

Teradata fails while using in-built function, INTERVAL, when used with MONTH specification for deriving dates on February month

```
SELECT Cast('2017-12-29' as date) - INTERVAL '10' MONTH;
SELECT Cast('2017-12-30' as date) - INTERVAL '10' MONTH;
SELECT Cast('2017-12-31' as date) - INTERVAL '10' MONTH;
SELECT Cast('2018-12-29' as date) - INTERVAL '10' MONTH;
SELECT Cast('2018-12-30' as date) - INTERVAL '10' MONTH;
SELECT Cast('2018-12-31' as date) - INTERVAL '10' MONTH;
SELECT Cast('2019-12-29' as date) - INTERVAL '10' MONTH;
SELECT Cast('2019-12-30' as date) - INTERVAL '10' MONTH;
SELECT Cast('2019-12-31' as date) - INTERVAL '10' MONTH;
SELECT Cast('2020-12-30' as date) - INTERVAL '10' MONTH;
SELECT Cast('2020-12-31' as date) - INTERVAL '10' MONTH;
```

or

```
SELECT CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '10' MONTH;-- << If current date is 29,30,31 day of December month Non leap year and 30,31 day of December month leap year>>
```

Comment: "fails" in what way? what is the error message?

Comment: It is doing as requested, going back 10 month. But because day `31` does not exist in february, you get `Invalid date`. I assume, that is why  '2020-12-29' is not in your list, because it works. As you found out, add_months accts different, using the end of month for non reachable days.

Answer (score 1):

Use Add_Months function instead of Interval function..

```
SELECT ADD_MONTHS(CAST ('2017-12-29' AS DATE),-10);
SELECT ADD_MONTHS(CURRENT_DATE,-10); -- << If current date is 29,30,31 day of December month Non leap year and 30,31 day of December month leap year>>
```